# Doubts on how to use the reactive paradigm with DDD - Domain repositories

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, reactive-programming, quarkus, ddd-repositories

I am working on a project where the DDD methodology is going to be used for the development and, due to the business needs, a reactive programming approach is going to be used.

I am modeling the domain, and some doubts have arisen when I was working on the definition of the repositories. I see the problem when implementing the repositories, through an adapter, because using reactive programming, all methods return Uni or Multi (Mutiny! will be used).
This is a problem because I am introducing dependencies with the framework in the domain, which violates DDD principles.

I have seen some posts on this forum (e.g.: [DDD Java with Spring - Repository returning Mono/Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450151/ddd-java-with-spring-repository-returning-mono-flux)), but I am not confident with the solution proposed. Has anyone been able to deal with this challenge effectively?

Comment: Does using `List` or `Set` in the domain also violate DDD principles? If it doesn't, why using `Uni` or `Multi` does? My understanding of domain modeling is that its very purpose is to build a language in which you can be precise. If you need to use reactive programming, that language naturally has to include terms (types, in this case) from reactive programming. That said -- if you really really really have to avoid Mutiny types in your domain layer, you can use the `CompletionStage` and (Java 9+) `Flow` types. It will make your life harder, but that's the price for "purity".

Comment: Hello @Ladicek! Thank you so mucho for your answer. It is not forbidden to use Mutiny types for the domain layer, and I perfectly understand your position, there are occasions like this, where I think we should not be so purist, and be more KISS.

Comment: If you want to be framework agnostic you can have your repository returning reactive stream Publisher (Multi extends it), it's less coupling as it's a standard interface.
You can also return CompletionStage, it's no coupling, but it's no more reactive but only async.

Comment: Thank you @loicmathieu, I will take a look at what you are saying. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your domain repository interface with generic type:

```
public interface MyRepositoryOutgoingPort <T> {
  T persist(My my);
}
```

And in reactive (e.g. Mongo) implementation you can wrap the result:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepositoryMongoImpl
extends ReactiveMongoRepository<My, UUID>,
    MyRepositoryOutgoingPort<Mono<My>> {

  @Override
  default Mono<My> persist(My my) {
    Mono<My> savedMy = save(my);
    return savedMy;
  }
}
```

Comment: That in my opinion is a brilliant idea.